# Multiple users for same JPA datasource

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I am currently using Spring Boot and Hibernate with a single datasource to access a single database. I need to read from and write to the database. Everything works fine until now.

Now, my project manager is a bit on the paranoid side when it comes to SQL injections despite our best efforts to parameterize any query that accepts any kind of user input. Because of this he asked me if it was possible to connect to the same database with two database users: one with read/write access and one with read only access. That way, for every query that only requires read access I could use the read only user and have an extra layer of protection against SQL injection attacks.

After a bit of googling I found Baeldung's excellent article [over here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-multiple-databases) about using multiple datasources. I guess I could adapt that approach, but I would need to duplicate each of my @Entity classes, which sounds like a horrible idea.

So my question is:

Is there a clever way of switching database users, so I can use one user for reading and another user for writing to a database?

Comment: No. Go to your project manager and tell him that this doesn't make sense.

Comment: @SimonMartinelli eh, there are certain scenarios where it'd make sense. just look at stackoverflow's data.stackexchange.com tool, if the stackexchange devs are worth their pay they'd use a read only user in the database for extra security (granted, stackexchange is big enough that they probably have an entire service dedicated to it, but the point still stands)

Comment: @KrustytheClown Read the question. The OP asks for two connections for the same Entity.

Comment: @SimonMartinelli Touche, that is indeed a pretty stupid idea

Answer (score 1):

You can do this, but this won't help you with SQL injections. Even if an attacker can only read data, that's usually enough to be a problem. The only reason for switching datasources is IMO to improve read performance by querying a secondary server. IMO only code reviews, training and careful coding will help you to avoid SQL injections.